# Basic rules for custom cluster configuration when using distributed learning in Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am investigating the use of custom scale tiers in the [Cloud Machine Learning API](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/concepts/training-overview#machine_type_table).

Now, I dont know precisely how to design my custom tiers! I basically use a CIFAR type of model, and I decided to use:

```
   if args.distributed:
      config['trainingInput']['scaleTier']  = 'CUSTOM'
      config['trainingInput']['masterType'] = 'complex_model_m'
      config['trainingInput']['workerType'] = 'complex_model_m'
      config['trainingInput']['parameterServerType'] = 'large_model'
      config['trainingInput']['workerCount'] = 12
      config['trainingInput']['parameterServerCount'] = 4

    yaml.dump(config, file('custom_config.yaml', 'w'))
```

But I hardly can find any information on how to dimension properly the cluster. Are there any "rules of thumb" out there? Or do we have to try and test?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: One rule of thumb is to assume that your workers have network capacity of 1Gbps. Calculate/benchmark how fast each of your worker does iteration, from there calculate amount of data sent per second, and that determines how many parameter server shards you need for a given number of workers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a small question : would you rather use a small amount of large computers, or a large amount of small computers ?

Comment: I guess it depends on cost, for something small like `CIFAR` you could use a single large computer

Comment: Actually, I am also looking for speed :-) but I will try various conf

Comment: Generally speaking a few big machines are better than many small machines. The reason is that all existing practical NN methods parallelize across machines using data parallelism (parameter server), which exhibits diminishing returns. For instance, for GoogleNet, 50 machines was a bit better than 10 machines, and going to 100 machines didn't bring any improvement at all. Model parallelism (ie different towers on different GPUs in CIFAR) doesn't have this diminishing property, but is sensitive to communication delays

Answer (score 2):

I have done a couple of small experiments, which might be worth sharing. My setup wasn't a 100% clean, but I think the rough idea is correct.

- The model looks like the cifar example, but with a lot of training data. I use averaging, decaying gradient as well as dropout.
- The "config" naming is (hopefully) explicit : basically `'M{masterCost}_PS{nParameterServer}x{parameterServerCost}_W{nWorker}x{workerCost}'`. For parameter servers, I always use "large_model".
- The "speed" is the 'global_step/s'
- The "cost" is the total ML unit
- And I call "efficiency" the number of 'global_step/second/ML unit'

Here are some partial results :

```
          config  cost  speed  efficiency
0             M1     1    0.5        0.50
1  M6_PS1x3_W2x6    21   10.0        0.48
2  M6_PS2x3_W2x6    24   10.0        0.42
3  M3_PS1x3_W3x3    15   11.0        0.73
4  M3_PS1x3_W5x3    21   15.9        0.76
5  M3_PS2x3_W4x3    21   15.1        0.72
6  M2_PS1x3_W5x2    15    7.7        0.51
```

I know that I should run many more experiments, but I have no time for this. 
If I have time, I will dig in deeper.

The main conclusions are :

- it might be worth trying a few setup on a small amount of iterations, just for deciding which config to use before going on hyper parameter tuning.
- What is good, is that the variation is quite limited. From 0.5 to 0.75, this is a 50% efficiency increase, it is significant but not explosive.
- For my specific problem, basically, large and expensive units are overkill for my problem. The best value I can get is using "complex_model_m".